Blender Character Rig for Unity saying "Root contains both Root motion and transform curves"
This error message allows the animations to play but when they do the character simply flies upwards instead of moving forwards as the root motion should work
Tried Changing the FBX setting to no avail and even tried to Re Rig the character but the same issue arose!!

There should be a checkbox for "allow root motion", try unchecking this. more info
